# Windows phone 8.1 can't reference System.Data

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a windows phone 8.1 apllication which has access to a local Database. I want  to handle the DB acess in a portable class library.
For introduction I looked as this webpage: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/hh202876(v=vs.105).aspx

But I can't even reference the required namespaces:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
```

And also I can't add none of them as reference.
Can someone tell me whats wrong

Comment: And did you follow the part which said to add a reference to the `System.Data.Linq` assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `SqlClient` in PCL projects because it is not built as a PCL and it is not cross platform. The `Data` namespace is unavailable in PCL projects and it is not listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The following assemblies are available within a Portable Class Library project:

> - `mscorlib.dll`
> - `System.dll`
> - `System.Core.dll`
> - `System.Xml.dll`
> - `System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll`
> - `System.Net.dll`
> - `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`
> - `System.ServiceModel.dll`
> - `System.Xml.Serialization.dll`
> - `System.Windows.dll (from Silverlight)`

Comment: Alright but I can't even add it the the main project (Windows Phone 8.1) and even if it would work, i don't want to have the Data Access Layer in my Main Project. Whats the sense behind that

Comment: @Ced... As I said it is not built as a PCL and it is not cross platform.