# missing System.UriFormatException class in PCL

Tags: c#, exception, portable-class-library

My crossplatform application throws System.UriFormatException but I cannot catch it because it does not exist! The class System.UriFormatException is not visible in my Visual Studio 2015 in PCL library. I was trying many different PCL profiles - no effect, still the exception is missing. But when creating simple library for .net 4.5 or Android the System.UriFormatException is available.

Is there something wrong with my IDE?

How can I catch this exception?

**EDIT:**

The *UriFormatException* is not available for PCL, but still this exception is thrown and I need to handle it. I can catch all exceptions and recognize the *UriFormatException* by simply comparing type name with string "UriFormatException". Is there another, more elegant way to solve problem?

Comment: Because it is not built as a PCL and it is not cross platform. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34674123/2946329

Comment: Thanks, I cant believe it is not in PCL. Is there some good way to handle such exceptions?

Comment: `UriFormatException` inherits from `FormatException`, and as far as I can tell all methods and properties in `UriFormatException` are also available in `FormatException`. `FormatException` is supported in most, if not all, PCL profiles. Would it suffice for you to catch `FormatException` instead?

Comment: I also think it is incorrect to classify this question as a duplicate. The question concerns handling non-PCL artifacts from a PCL library. This is a very different question from acknowledging that a specific class or namespace is not available in PCL.

Comment: Thanks @AndersGustafsson, FormatException solved my problem. But still handling not available exceptions is an opened case.

Comment: If you absolutely must handle platform specific exception types explicitly, I recommend that you define an interface or abstract class in your PCL library, and delegate the exception handling to a platform specific implementation of that interface/abstract class.