# Error CS0012: The type 'DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, database-connection

I got this error

**Error CS0012: The type 'DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. (CS0012)**

I'm trying to do this:

```
private void SetConnection()
{
   sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=kyriosDB.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
}


public void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
{
    SetConnection();
    sql_con.Open();
    sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
    sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
    sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql_con.Close();
}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: The error-message is self-explanatory. Add a reference to `System.Data`.

Comment: @S.Akbari I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Mac os. How can I do that?

Comment: Try adding a 'using' statement at the top of the code page.

Comment: So have a look here maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/34674123/2946329

Comment: @wazz no, adding a `using` directive at the top of the code file does **not** add a reference. That is not the fix here.

Comment: @RuiPedroИИ in *regular* VS you would right click on the project or the references folder in the solution explorer; I'm don't use the Mac version, but I'm guessing it is pretty similar ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by going to Project - Add references then I manually add System.Data on Mac... I don't know about VS windows but hopefully it's the same